# n-bit signed number where n is not a power of 2

Tags: c++, c, integer, bit

Is it possible to have for example 6-bit signed integer or 11-bit signed integer (or any n-bit integer where n != 2^x) in C or C++?

Comment: There are no "built-in" types that are like that, however, you can simulate them.

Comment: See [<cstdint>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) for a listing

Comment: @AndyG: The opposite is correct actually. C does not mandate a specific bit-width. There have been and still are implementations with e.g. 24 bit integers and `char`s. Just none with less than 8 bits.

Comment: This is tied to machine architecture. If the machine's fundamental addressable memory unit was 6 bits wide, the type char would be 6 bits wide but you would declare a char as you would on a "8 bit"  machine; the same with int and long, etc.. the compiler would take care of this transparently.  What would change is the range of those types. If you need to emulate such a machine, you will have to implement this yourself on a machine that has an 8-bit fundamental memory addressable unit.

Comment: @Olaf Well, any with fewer than 8 bits are not C, not C++, since both C and C++ require at least 8 bits, but I do think I recall reading about real implementations that had a narrower char but were otherwise pretty C-like.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-bit.  Next April 1, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-9_and_UTF-18

Comment: @hvd: I wrote that in my comment already, didn't I? Well, you obviously can have any language which has a C-like syntax (C++ would be one, Java another), but still that would not be C, so I don't see the point in that. (Some compilers allowed to declare addressable single-bit types, e.g. for 8051 targets, but they would not be C compilers anymore.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes. Consider my foot in my mouth.

Comment: @Olaf That's not what I got from your comment. Your comment reads to me as if all almost-C implementations also had at least 8 bits. If that's not what you meant, then fine, but then it's probably good to leave the comments here to clear it up for others that read your comment the same way I did.

Comment: @hvd: Let's say it can be missinterpreted. I might better have swapped the last two sentences. But I don't think it can be missread as there are/have been implementations with less than 8 bits. Anyway, I don't intend to delete your comments (even if I could), so all is fine. On second thought about less-than-8 bitwidth types: I think you can have them, but they still have to be aligned at `char` boundaries. So effectively they are `char` where only a portion is used. Not sure if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, that makes sense. Though I'm not aware of any implementations where the number of sign+value bits in any integer type is fewer than `char`, integer types with padding bits in general have definitely been used on real-world implementations.

Comment: @hvd: Consider a 4-bit CPU. (I luckily never had to write code for them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly *possible* that a C or C++ implementation could provide types that are sized like this, but most implementations won't provide built-in types with sizes like these because (1) it's uncommon to encounter them and (2) most processors don't support direct operations on types like these.

If you're trying to use these integers as groups of binary flags, consider using `std::bitset` as the other answers have suggested. This might even be a better option, since it explicitly indicates that you're using a group of flags. For example:

```
std::bitset<6> bits; // Six independent bit flags
bits[3] = true;      // Set the third flag
```

If you're trying to use them as actual integer types, just constrained by the number of bits they use, consider using bitfields, like this:

```
struct uint6_t {
    uint64_t value : 6; // 6 bits, unsigned
};
struct int6_t {
    int64_t value : 6;  // 6 bits, signed
};
```

You can then use `uint6_t`'s `value` field as a six-bit integer. This will only work for sizes that are smaller than the size of the underlying type you use inside the bitfield, which should work for sizes like 6 or 11 but not for sizes like 137 or 271. One note - the actual size of these objects will likely not be six bits because of the padding bits introduced by the compiler, but they will function like six-bit integers nonetheless.

Apparently C++ templates allow you to do something like this:

```
template <unsigned int NumBits> struct uint {
    uint64_t data : NumBits;
};
template <unsigned int NumBits> struct Int {
    int64_t data : NumBits;
};

uint<6> value;
value.data = 0; // Or other uses

Int<6> value;
value.data = -1; // Or other uses
```

**EDIT**: Based on what you're trying to do, it seems like you're looking for something like this:

```
uint<6> value;
value.data = -3;
std::cout << value.data << std::endl; // Prints 3
```

Comment: Good approach, but how would you address the _signed_ part in the OP's question? Wouldn't there some operations needed to be overloaded?

Comment: What I actually trying to achieve is this:
`std::bitset<8> n(-3);
std::cout<< static_cast<signed int>(n.to_ulong()); // this is NOT -3 but 253 but I would love it to be -3`

Comment: @templatetypedef Ey, that easy. Cool.

Comment: @carobnodrvo Answer updated to address what you're trying to do.

Comment: The last update on this post solves my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use bitfields to simulate this:

```
struct int6_t{
    int32_t intPart : 6; // 6 bit integer
}

int_6_t mySilly6bitInt;
mySilly6bitInt.intPart = 5;
```

Comment: Is the `reserved` field necessary here?

Comment: Rather than `int32_t`, recommend `signed int`.  `int` is not defined as `int32_t`.

Comment: @templatetypedef No, but it describes the remainder of the int, usually good as a placeholder in bitfields to know how much of the type is left.

Comment: @templatetypedef sorry, i was thinking for in a union, you are right, unnecassary.

Comment: Check my comment on @templatetypedef s post please.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ both require that a byte, an `unsigned char`, is at least 8 bits. But there is no upper limit, and there is no restriction to powers of two. So in principle `CHAR_BIT` (the number of bits per byte) can be e.g. 10.

Mostly this is for backward compatibility. In earlier times there were computers based on e.g. [12-bit bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-bit). To cater to modern 8-bit systems C99 introduced the `stdint.h` header, which provides types that, if they're supported, guarantee a multiple of 8 bits.

For the in-practice you can simulate types with any number of bits, at a cost of some run-time overhead.